# Float error when evaluation function in python?

Tags: python, excel

So I'm trying to call values from an Excel sheet to use in a function in python. I want the code to multiply a variable, defined in the code, by a value from one cell, and then to add another value from another cell. I'm using parser to define an expression. This is what I have written:

```
    beam_energy = 12
    import parser
    for a in range(1,4):
        formula = "energy_vs_stopping_power_functions.cell(a,1).value*x"
        energy = parser.expr(formula).compile()
        x = beam_energy
        print eval(energy) + energy_vs_stopping_power_functions.cell(a,2).value
```

This exact bit of code worked fine for me just minutes ago, and gave me the correct values, but for whatever reason, it now just returns `"TypeError: 'float' object is not callable."` I have no idea what went wrong, especially since literally this exact code just worked.

Is there any easier way for me to evaluate a linear function in python?

Answer (score 0):

First - easier way to evaluate a linear function:

```
def make_linear_fn(a, b):
    def linear_fn(x):
        return a * x + b
    return linear_fn

energy = linear_fn(-200., 1800.)

energy(5)    # returns 800.0 (== -200.0 * 5 + 1800.0)
```

Second: this

```
for a in range(1,4):
    formula = "energy_vs_stopping_power_functions.cell(a,1).value*x"
    energy = parser.expr(formula).compile()
    x = beam_energy
    print eval(energy)
```

could be simplified to

```
for a in range(1, 4):    # produces 1, 2, 3
    print(evspf.cell(a, 1).value * beam_energy)
```